# How to find matches that do not include a string in regular expressions

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create a regular expression that will match #rn: but not if it is followed by msg.

So

```
#rn:abc -> matches
#rn:msh -> matches
#rn:xy -> matches
#rn:defg -> matches
#rn:msg - does not match
```

I have tried `\#rn\:[^m][^s][^g]` and `\#rn\:[^(msg)]` but they don't work.

Can it be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\#rn\:(?!msg)
```

This shoudl do it for you.Here `lookahead` ensure that after `#rn:` there is not `msg`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/tX2bH4/28